# Access 2016 Runtime error 3167 when calling Edit on a Recordset, but only with an Umlaut in the data

Tags: vba, postgresql, ms-access, ms-access-2016, psqlodbc

I have to maintain some legacy database system that uses MS Access 2016 as a frontend. The data is stored in a PostgreSQL database and connection is made with psqlODBC.

There is a form, from where I can select some dataset, make some edits and save it back. This is where the trouble starts.

The table looks like this

- `projectnumber` (Primary key) name
- `group` (Primary key) name
- `cost` numeric

The relevant code looks like this

```
        Dim rs As Recordset
        Dim dbs As Database
        Set dbs = CurrentDb
        Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset("public_SomeTable", dbOpenDynaset)
        rs.FindFirst ("[projectnumber] = '" & projektnumber & "'" & " And [group] ='" & group & "'")
        rs.Edit
        rs!cost = cost
        rs.Update
        rs.Close
```

This seems to work fine, unless group contains an Umlaut, i.e. *Motorhead* works fine, but *Motörhead* does not.
In that case, I get `runtime error 3167: Record deleted`.
Which is confusing, as the record still exists

Comment: This is one reason search on number value is better and why text values make poor keys. Can you use Replace on the character to substitute? `"Replace([group], Chr(246), 'o') = '" & Replace(group, Chr(246), "o") & "'"`. Are there any other characters that could cause same issue?

Comment: Edit code will error if record is not found. Follow FindFirst with `If Not rs.NoMatch Then`. Why not open recordset with criteria for specific record then don't need FindFirst? Test for empty recordset. Or just run an UPDATE action SQL and don't even open recordset? Regardless, will still have issue of special character in WHERE clause.

Comment: If this is Access connected to postgresql tables, why not use bound form opened to record for edit? Why VBA and recordset? Of course, even applying filter to form could have same issue.

Comment: [This old article about the interaction of DAO and ODBC](https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/172/Q172339/) may help.

Comment: This is probably just an encoding problem, and you have to set the client encoding correctly. Is there anything in the PostgreSQL server log?

Comment: As mentioned, this is a legacy project, which has many flaws.

I tried doing it directly with an `UPDATE` statement, i.e.
`dbs.Execute "Update public_SomeTable Set cost = " & cost & " WHERE (projectnummer = '" & projectnummer & "' And group = '" & group & "');" but the update fails again for the Umlaut, even if I do not check for the 'group'.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion?